# SQL merge statement with Joins

Tags: sql, merge, sql-merge

I am trying to use a merge statement for upsert operation. I want to do something like below where I join the both target and source table to the Student table for a unique key that only exists in the student table. Just to keep in mind, I cannot join StudentID. There could be a duplicate in my code. I need to join the schoolID for uniqueness.

```
Merge into GuardianTo gto inner join StudentTo sto on gto.fkStudentId = sto.StudentID
Using (Select * from GuardianFrom gfrom inner join StudentFrom sfrom on gfrom.fkStudentId = sfrom.StudentID) from
ON gto.guardianId = from.guardianId and sto.SchoolID = from.SchoolID
When....
```

I need to join the target guardianTo table with studentTo table to get the unique key of SchoolID. and match this ID with From tables. I know that this could be done in a separate insert and update statement (not merge), but is there a way to do something like the above using merge statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL you can do a merge like the code below. You need to supply a list of column names to use from your source query and then update/insert the columns you need in your target table (GuardianTo).

```
Merge into GuardianTo gto 
Using (Select * from GuardianFrom gfrom inner join StudentFrom sfrom on gfrom.fkStudentId = sfrom.StudentID ) AS source (<column names in GuardianFrom, Studentfrom go here> )
ON (gto.guardianId = source.guardianId and gto.SchoolID = source.SchoolID)        
WHEN MATCHED THEN          
UPDATE SET <column in GuardianTo>= source.<column from source above> /* add any additional columns to update here*/
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN            
INSERT (guardianId, SchoolID, StudentID /* add any additional columns to insert here*/)            
VALUES (source.guardianId, source.SchoolID, source.StudentID /* add any additional columns from the source to insert here*/);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, my problem is that GuardianTo table does not have the schoolID. It needs to join with the Student table to get the SchoolID. I need both GuardianFrom table and GuardianTo table to join with the Student table to retrieve the SchoolID and match on those. Basically, gto.SchoolID in code line 3 does not exist. it needs to join with the student table to retrieve the value.

Comment: Ok, but you said you could get the work done using separate insert and update statements. Just change whatever you need in the USING/ON clause to match rows in the GuardianTo table to the other two tables. You can add the Student table a second time in the using clause if necessary. 
As long as you can write a SQL with these tables to find out when to update and when to insert you can use the merge. 
However you may find that performance gets worse with merge compared to insert/update. Depending on the use case it may also be easier to separate into insert/update.

Comment: I would need to see the table definitions and some sample data to be able to help with the exact SQL that is needed.